# JPA is not creating TIME part of TIMESTAMP

Tags: jpa, timestamp

I have an entity like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCTS")
public class Feed implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1732936132016478456L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "IMAGE_PATH")
    private String imagePath;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="UPLOADER", nullable = false)
    private User uploader;

    @Column(name = "TAGS")
    private String tags;

    @Column(name = "DATE", columnDefinition="")
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "LINK")
    private String link;
}
```

I'm using below code to create entity

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public Feed createFeed(Feed feed) {
        this.entityManager.persist(feed);
        this.entityManager.flush();
    }
```

Everything is working perfectly but DATE column which is of type timestamp and set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default is only populating Date part not time part.
I tried firing manual query and that populated timestamp properly.
Am I missing anything there?

Answer (score 0):

If the Date is of type `java.sql.Date` JPA will only store the Date part in the database field.

If it's `java.util.Date` you must add `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` to also store the time part.

The `TemporalType` defines the precision of the date.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html

Comment: Earlier i was using Temporal some different reason. Just tried again but it failed. Still updating date only.

Comment: One point to note: I am not updating date field myself. I expect DB to update it and hence i have current_timestamp as default for that column

Comment: what database are you using and what data type is your date of?

Comment: I am using mysql and type is timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
I still don't know the reason and that is why i am not marking this as answer.
I annotated my date variable with `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` and just that did the trick.
One thing to note: I had used java.util.Date